# Error rendering static html

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

This code:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
var indexTemplate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/index.html');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.end(ejs.render(indexTemplate, {}));
});
```

Gives me the following error

> TypeError: Object         Address                     
>                has no method 'substr'
>       at Object.parse (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:152:20)
>       at /home/lowerkey/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:192:13
>       at Object.render (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:235:10)
>       at /home/lowerkey/workspace/address book/server/server.js:60:14
>       at callbacks (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
>       at param (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
>       at pass (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
>       at Router._dispatch (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
>       at Object.handle (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
>       at next (/home/lowerkey/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:203:15)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your **indexTemplate** variable actually contains buffer instead of string, due to default encoding of the readFile return value. You may want to try to add the **encoding** in **readFileSync** 2nd parameter to set it, like the following:

```
...
var indexTemplate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/index.html', 'utf8');
...
```